# Передать адрес файла в программу из контекстного меню

Tags: windows, реестр

Есть программа считающая хэш, я добавил ее в контекстное меню, с каким параметром ее нужно запустить, чтобы передать путь файла, в данный момент выглядит так, но -here - просто запускает ее в текущей папке, но не передает имя файла [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через %u обычно, посмотри в других ветках